# Angular 2 make function available in ng-content

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a dropdown with a template like this:

```
<div class="dropdown-trigger" (click)="contentToggle()">
     <ng-content select="dropdown-trigger"></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-content" *ngIf="showContent">
     <ng-content select="dropdown-content"></ng-content>
</div>
```

I'd like to be able to use `contentToggle()` in whatever I put in the `ng-content` so that I can have additional elements that can be used to close the dropdown, for example I might want a close button... What's the best way to do this?

Comment: what is that you are trying to do. explain as it is unclear

Comment: @Aravind added more detail, is that enough?

Comment: this is handled by bootstrap by default.

Comment: @Aravind I'm not using bootstrap

Comment: create a plunker I will fix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
<dropdown #dropdown>
  <button dropdownTrigger (click)="dropdown.toggleDropdown()">Click me</button>
</dropdown>
```

You just assign a local template variable to the component which gives you access to everything the component has in it. Including the function you want to call.

Note that you should/need to also change the `select` bits to this:

```
<ng-content select="[dropdownTrigger]"></ng-content>
<ng-content select="[dropdownContent]"></ng-content>
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Angular allow you to do this trick, Example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component(){...}
export class DropdownComponent {
   toggleDropdown() {...}
}

//parent.component.html
<dropdown-content #myDropdown>
  <a (click)="myDropdown.toggleDropdown()">Close the dropdown</a>
</dropdown-content>
```

If you want to get a callback to the event I recommend you to read the [Output Decorator](http://learnangular2.com/outputs/)